# SQL: What query returns if one table is a subset of another?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two type-compatible tables; A and B. I would like a SQL query that will tell me if all elements of B are also elements of A.

Example 1:

```
     Table A
c1      | c2
--------+--------
"Hello" | "World"
"Hello" | "Kitty"
"Hello" | "pretty"

     Table B
c1      | c2
--------+--------
"Hello" | "World"
"Hello" | "Kitty"

expected: TRUE
```

Example 2:

```
     Table A
c1      | c2
--------+--------
"Cat"   | 1
"Gato"  | 2
"Neko"  | 3

     Table B
c1      | c2
--------+--------
"Cat"   | 1
"Chat"  | 4

expected: FALSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will attempt to match all the values in table `b` against table `a`, using both columns `c1` and `c2`.

If they match, the `equals` result of the query will be `true`, otherwise `false`.

Working example: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d1N7ZaUSdogoTVCYefpdc1/1

```
SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 AS equal
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a USING (c1, c2)
WHERE a.c1 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach could be union and left join

```
select case when t2.col is not null then 'all elements of B are also elements of A.' else null end  from
(
select distinct c1 as col from A 
union
select distinct c2 from A
) t1
left join
(
select distinct c1 as col from B
union
select distinct c2 from B
) t2 on t1.col=t2.col
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. I can't take the union of c1 and c2, because they have different types. I'll update the example right away.

Comment: @PabloRepetto i consider your sample data and for your sample data it will work